# Delete top part of box shadow

Tags: shadow

I am using something like this and would like to delete the top shadow because it doesn't look good. Any ideas ?

```
div#custom_html-5.widget_text.widget.widget_custom_html {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div#custom_html-5.widget_text.widget.widget_custom_html:before {
      content: "";
      height: 7px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: -7px;
      background: inherit;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

You can use this.

Comment: oh i am so sorry

Answer (score 0):

I am sending the full code of what I am trying to do, so you can understand:

```
div#search-2.widget.widget_search { 
 margin-bottom: 20px
}
div#search-2.widget.widget_search { 
     border: 1px solid #dcdcdc
}
div#search-2.widget.widget_search {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px black
}
div#search-2.widget.widget_search { 
 padding-bottom: 20px
}
div#search-2.widget.widget_search { 
 padding-top: 10px
}
div#search-2.widget.widget_search {
    border-bottom: none;
}
div#custom_html-5.widget_text.widget.widget_custom_html {
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc
}
div#custom_html-5.widget_text.widget.widget_custom_html {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px black
}
#custom_html-5.widget_text.widget.widget_custom_html {
 border-top: none;
}
div#custom_html-5.widget_text.widget.widget_custom_html {
    margin-top: -20px
}
div#custom_html-5.widget_text.widget.widget_custom_html {
 padding-bottom: 10px
}
```